# Conent Transition NPE with empty shared elements

Tags: android, android-animation

I am adding content transitions to a pretty large app and in most cases I do not have any shared elements but still want to use the transition animations. I have tracked the problem down to this line of code:

```
ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, ????);
```

I have tried setting Pair array to null or an empty array and I have tried just leaving it out. Everything results in the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewRootImpl.setPausedForTransition(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

However, I only get this error on Android 6.0+, it works fine on any version of Android 5. Am I trying to do this the wrong way?

Comment: Did you found a solution for this issue?

Comment: Not a real answer hence the comment. The exception doesn't seem to break anything important, so catching the exception makes the animation work just fine

Answer (score 2):

I did a bunch of digging in the source code and it looks like this is caused by a [missed null pointer check that got fixed for Nougat](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/5fddd4ca581aeb7c6b526628cfbf7915a2e20574%5E%21/core/java/android/app/ActivityTransitionCoordinator.java).

I've got no clue how to work around it on 6.x though, unfortunately. I suppose you could add a 6.x `try`/`catch` if it's really killing you in terms of crashes, but that may also catch a bunch of other stuff you may not want it to.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an exact answer, rather a workaround; but I have managed to resolve this by postponing animations using `handler.postDelayed(...)` and `Runnable`.

You can check out the code of my solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932405/) question.

To be honest, it's still a lil bit too hacky for me and that's why I'm still waiting for answers with more elegant solutions. Moreover, I suppose that it only makes sense in cases similar to mine, when transitions are invoked right after creating the view.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. The issue was that I was setting

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

Which killed the activity from which I was launching the transition. Removing that fixed the issue for me on Android M.