# ViewRootImpl.setPausedForTransition(boolean) NullPointerException in ActivityTransitionCoordinator when transition to other Activity invoked too early

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-support-library, android-transitions

In my Android app, I have a splash screen where I do some setup and loading. My app uses default `explode` as a `windowEnterTransition` and a `windowExitTransition` and a `changeImageTransform` plus `changeBounds` transition set as a `windowSharedElementEnterTransition` and `windowSharedElementExitTransition`. For convenience, I start the next `Activity` using a static method where I pass the current `Activity` as a `Context` and a shared element. The code is provided in the second part of this post.

One of the scenarios is that there is nothing to load, so app almost immediately fires the next `Activity`. The problem is that in this case app somehow enigmatically crashes in an `ActivityTransitionCoordinator` with a stack given in the next part of this post. Debugging of the internals shows that `ViewRootImpl` that is achieved there is null and there is no null check, so invoking `viewRoot.setPausedForTransition(false)` throws a `NullPointerException`. You can find this unlucky spot marked in the code below.

To focus on this failing scenario, let’s make an assumption that a logic deciding that there is nothing to load and the next `Activity` should be started immediately is so simple, that it could be simplified to just starting the mentioned activity.

It makes no difference if a start of the second `Activity` is invoked in `onCreate()`, `onResume()`, or `onEnterAnimationComplete()` method. I even tried adding a listener on a Transition acquired by calling `getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition()` and `getWindow().getEnterTransition()` to be allowed to start the next `Activity` when transitions are finished. The given `Transitions` are not null, but app never goes into methods of attached listeners.

The workaround I use now is just to schedule a `Runnable` to make an invoking of the next `Activity` delayed.

I’m wondering if this is an `Android` (a `SupportLibrary` to be more specific) issue, or I missed something. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

A stacktrace:

```java
08-12 00:35:32.550 26453-26453/com.faver.mkoslacz.faverdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.faver.mkoslacz.faverdemo, PID: 26453
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewRootImpl.setPausedForTransition(boolean)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityTransitionCoordinator.startInputWhenTransitionsComplete(ActivityTransitionCoordinator.java:897)
at android.app.ActivityTransitionCoordinator.viewsTransitionComplete(ActivityTransitionCoordinator.java:885)
at android.app.ExitTransitionCoordinator.getExitTransition(ExitTransitionCoordinator.java:318)
at android.app.ExitTransitionCoordinator.beginTransitions(ExitTransitionCoordinator.java:365)
at android.app.ExitTransitionCoordinator.-wrap0(ExitTransitionCoordinator.java)
at android.app.ExitTransitionCoordinator$4.run(ExitTransitionCoordinator.java:216)
at android.app.ActivityTransitionCoordinator.startTransition(ActivityTransitionCoordinator.java:773)
at android.app.ExitTransitionCoordinator.startExit(ExitTransitionCoordinator.java:213)
at android.app.ActivityTransitionState.startExitOutTransition(ActivityTransitionState.java:317)
at android.app.Activity.cancelInputsAndStartExitTransition(Activity.java:3960)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3936)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4196)
at com.faver.mkoslacz.faverdemo.activity.AuthorizationActivity.startWithTransiton(AuthorizationActivity.java:45)
at com.faver.mkoslacz.faverdemo.activity.SplashActivity.onEnterAnimationComplete(SplashActivity.java:27)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchEnterAnimationComplete(Activity.java:5852)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleEnterAnimationComplete(ActivityThread.java:2668)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap10(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1558)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

A code failing in `ActivityTransitionAnimator`:

```java
private void startInputWhenTransitionsComplete() {
    if (mViewsTransitionComplete && mSharedElementTransitionComplete) {
        final View decor = getDecor();
        if (decor != null) {
            final ViewRootImpl viewRoot = decor.getViewRootImpl(); // it's null
            viewRoot.setPausedForTransition(false); // crashes here
        }
        onTransitionsComplete();
    }
}
```

A method starting the next `Activity`:

```java
public static void startWithTransiton(Activity activity, android.view.View logo) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, AuthorizationActivity.class);
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat
            .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                    activity,
                    logo,
                    activity.getString(R.string.logoTransfer));
    activity.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
}
```

The splash `Activity` contents (simplified):

```java
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "SplashActivity";

    private View logo;
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        logo = findViewById(R.id.logo);

//        AuthorizationActivity.startWithTransiton(this, logo); // will fail

        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            AuthorizationActivity.startWithTransiton(this, logo); // executes flawlessly
        }, 300);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Transition sharedElementEnterTransition = getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition();
            if (sharedElementEnterTransition != null) {
                sharedElementEnterTransition.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onTransitionStart: never executes");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onTransitionEnd: never executes");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onTransitionCancel: never executes");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onTransitionPause: never executes");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onTransitionResume: never executes");
                    }
                });
            }

            Transition enterTransition = getWindow().getEnterTransition();
            if (enterTransition != null) {
                enterTransition.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onTransitionStart: never executes");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onTransitionEnd: never executes");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onTransitionCancel: never executes");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onTransitionPause: never executes");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onTransitionResume: never executes");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
//        AuthorizationActivity.startWithTransiton(this, logo); // will fail
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnterAnimationComplete() {
        super.onEnterAnimationComplete();
//        AuthorizationActivity.startWithTransiton(this, logo); // will fail
    }
}
```

Comment: See my comment on a similar question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557479/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557479/conent-transition-npe-with-empty-shared-elements#comment66253761_36557479)

Comment: @Olumide Actually, applying your suggestion makes my animations do not work. My workaround postpones them, but they work at least. Sorry :(

Comment: it works for me though so idk

Answer (score 5):

I'm also facing same issue while working with Explode Activity transition,I find one thing this code running normally in Lollipop version, But crashed above Lollipop.
Even i can't find out the reason for crashing. But i resolve it another way. Just **put delay in activity transition**. I given my code below

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            navigate();
        }
    },500);
}

private void navigate() {
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this);
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
}}
```

After adding this working normally in all version.

Comment: Well, that's exactly the workaround I described in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Handler you can navigate to the next activity using your root view `post` method

```
findViewById(<Your activity root view id>).post(() -> navigate());
```

In general, the root view could be `android.R.id.content`